# How to create PDF on Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, pdf

I need to create & display a PDF document in Silverlight 4.

PDF document will be generated dynamically.

The PDF document will contain plain text & some images.

Is there any API I can use to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: Rather late.. But this will help you printing multiple pages. http://silverlightpdf.codeplex.com/discussions/241386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: http://silverlightpdf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, it's like taking a screenshot of the xaml file & saving it as PDF :)

Comment: you will have some trouble with multi page printing

Answer (score 0):

Yes! We create PDF Document. In silverlight By using  PDFSharp.dll.
It's Opensource dll file.

You can download the dll file below Link
http://www.pdfsharp.net/Downloads.ashx

Please click below link for reference puprpose.

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Booklet-sample.ashx
as so many examples as given its easy to understand.