# create a PDF document in Silverlight

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight-4.0, .net-framework-version, pdfsharp

I need to convert an excel file to save/display as a PDF document. This is in Silverlight Application. PDF document will be generated dynamically. The PDF document will contain plain text. I tried to download the nuget package.

The PDFSharp Library mentioned in one of the posts helped, [How to create PDF on Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523715/how-to-create-pdf-on-silverlight-4)

I had to look for an older version which is compatible with silverlight. My application is using .net framework 4.
Would anyone know where I could find the dll for PDFSharp? I am unable to install using the nuget package.

Message:
Add reference problem in silverlight: You can't add a reference to dll as it was not built against the silverlight runtime

Error:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'PDFsharp-sl
> 1.50.4000-beta3b'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but  the package
> does not contain any assembly references or content files that are
> compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
> package author.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you took the Silverlight version of the library, but attempted to add it to a project that does not compile against Silverlight.

You have two options:

- Use the NuGet package for Silverlight
- Download the PDFsharp source code and reference the projects for Silverlight

The second approach can be helpful for debugging and allows you to change the Silverlight version compiled for.